# How to iterate map in a template using play framework 1.4.2

Tags: groovy, java-8, playframework-1.x

I have got a map where the key is a object but the value is a list object. I am using play framework 1.4.2 (using groovy template).

This is the map:

```
Map<Object, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

How can iterating through the map values in a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use entrySet() to iterate over the map just like you would do in java (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46908/4583412)), then create a variable in a groovy script to get the value and key :

```
#{list items:map.entrySet(), as:'set' }
  ∗{print the key}*
  ${set.key}
  *{iterate over value list }∗
  #{list items: set.value, as:'itemValue'}
    ${itemValue}
  #{/list}

#{/list}
```

For more information about groovy scripts in play see : [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/templates#Scripts)

Answer (score 1):

To walk through the map values you need to get values by calling [Map#values()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) as follows:

```
#{list map.values()}
Value of your map is ${_}
#{/list}
```

To walk through values of your lists of values of your map, you need to use **list** tag twice as follows:

```
#{list map.values()}
  #{list _}
    Value of your list is ${_}
  #{/list}
  #{else}Your list is empty#{/else}
#{/list}
```

Other useful examples of using **list** tag you can find in a [cheatsheet](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/cheatsheet/templates) of play documentation, for example:

```
#{list items:0..10, as:'i'} 
  ${i} 
#{/list}

#{list items:'a'..'z', as:'l'}
  ${l} ${l_isLast ?'':'|' }
#{/list}

#{list users}
  ${_}
#{/list}

Loop constructs
#{list items:task, as:'task'}
  ${task}
#{/list}
#{else}No tasks on the list#{/else}
Tip: Else can be used along with list
```